# What's the connection between Galois objects and Galois closed objects?

Tags: ct.category-theory, galois-theory

An object in a free coproduct completion is *Galois closed* if it has no nontrivial coverings, i.e every [covering morphism](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/239994/categorification-of-covering-morphisms) is split by the identity.

An object of a Galois category is a *Galois object* if its quotient by its automorphism group is the terminal object.

What is the connection between Galois objects and Galois closed objects?

Comment: One might ask here whether every Galois closed object is a Galois object. Do you mean anything else?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე that and any other implications between them under reasonable conditions.

Comment: I see only one other implication, and it is false under any reasonable conditions.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Could you explain/give intuition as to why the other implication is false? What about the implication in your first comment?

Comment: Consider $G$-sets (a typical example): a Galois object is one with all of its orbits isomorphic to each other, i. e. all stabilizers conjugate to each other. This is a Galois closed object iff all these stabilizers are trivial.